# Python xml.dom.minidom schema validation

Tags: python, xml, validation, python-2.7, xsd

Is there any pure Python way to validate XML files with XSD. My python version is 2.x (2.6/2.7) and the code is already using `xml.dom.minidom` for XML parsing. There are so many answers on StackOverflow but most are using ElementTree or lxml.

Is there any implementation with `xml.dom.minidom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any thing using minidom, so I used lxml to validate xml against xsd

```
from lxml import etree

xmlschema_doc = etree.parse('schema.xsd')
xml_doc = etree.parse('my.xml')
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

if xmlschema.validate(xml_doc):
   print 'Valid xml'
else:
   print 'Invalid xml'
```

we can also use `xmlschema.assertValid(xml_doc)` to raise assertion exception

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, miniDom is a library for interacting with the [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (DOM) API. As wikipedia states:

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and language-independent convention for representing and interacting with objects in HTML, XHTML and XML documents.

It doesn't focus on the "validity" of the document, just that it is well-formed and able to be parsed and browsed.

As such, miniDom won't have any XML validation capability as this is beyond the scope of the DOM API.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought if there any other modules which can do this with the help of minidom, no elementtree. I didn't wanted to use lxml